# Get row number from of data point from event_data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have been creating a data viewer app using shiny and plotly. I want to make a create a multi dimensional scaling view of my data, and then click on a data point to be able to view the individual point as a barplot. I was inspired by [this](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-hover-events/) example.

Here is a minimal almost working example:

## The ui.r file

```
library(shiny)
library(mlbench)
library(plotly)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

# Load the data
allDat <- iris[,-5]

# ui.R definition
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Set theme
  theme = shinytheme("spacelab"),

  # Some help text
  h2("Inspect each element in iris data set"),
  h4("This a shiny app exploiting coupled events in plotly"),
  tags$ol(
    tags$li("The first chart showcases", tags$code("plotly_click"))
  ),

  # Vertical space
  tags$hr(),

  # First row
  fixedRow(
    column(6, plotlyOutput("Plot1", height = "600px")),
    column(6, plotlyOutput("Plot2", height = "600px"))),

  tags$hr())
```

## The server.r file

```
# server.R definition
server <- function(input, output){

  d <- dist(allDat) # euclidean distances between the rows
  fit <- cmdscale(d,eig=TRUE, k=2) # k is the number of dim

  # plot solution
  x <- fit$points[,1]
  y <- fit$points[,2]
  plot.df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,allDat)

  output$Plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly(plot.df, x = x, y = y, mode="markers", source = "mds") %>%
      layout(title = "MDS of iris data",
             plot_bgcolor = "6A446F")
  })

  # Coupled event 2
  output$Plot2 <- renderPlotly({

    # Try to get the mouse click data
    event.data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "mds")

    # If NULL dont do anything
    if(is.null(event.data) == T) return(NULL)

    # I need the row of the data in the allDat data frame
    # pretty sure this is not correct
    ind <- as.numeric(event.data[2])

    p1 <- plot_ly(x = colnames(allDat), y=as.numeric(allDat[ind,]),type="bar")

  })

}
```

To run this, put these two files in a folder called something, e.g. dataViewer, then run `runApp("dataViewer")` from the directory that contains the dataViewer folder.

## What is the question and what am I seeking?

I do not understand the output that comes from the `event_data` function. I want to be able to click on a point on the scatter plot and extract the row number of that data point from the `allDat` data frame, or the `plot.df` data frame, because it should be the same. Then I want to use that row number to further visualize that specific point in the barplot on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the `event.data` object, and think the value you are looking for is `event.data$pointNumber` (which starts with 0 so you need to use `event.data$pointNumber + 1` to identify the line).

`event.data` is a list with four names: `curveNumber`, `pointNumber`, `x` and `y`.

Comment: thanks for the response! I was looking [here](https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/) and there is a comment on this: "pointNumber: Index of the data point being charted. Note that this is linked to curveNumber and starts from 0". So this starts from 0 and is somehow linked to the `curveNumber`, which I have no idea what is. So is this then the index in the data frame used to plot, or some other index?

Comment: Ok, cheers! Hope this will help others that might run into this! I am new to plotly and shiny, but if I may ask, how did you inspect the event.data object?

Comment: Edit: I must have miscounted, but it does seem that `pointNumber` starts with 0, so you should use `event.data$pointNumber + 1` to identify the line.

Comment: It might then be that the index in the data frame is the `pointNumber` index + 1.

Comment: You can use http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html to debug your application, although I simply added a textOutput to display a summary of the object and the names

Comment: I figured it out, the index I need is `ind <- event.data$pointNumber + 1`

Comment: just for reference for others - it isn't recommended to use `pointNumber` to find rows. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46306186/2868715)