# How to use plotly to return the same event_data information for selected points even after modifying the data

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple: when the user clicks on a data point or select multiple points with lasso selection, I want to draw these points in a different colour. In order to do that, I look at what points are selected, and add a `col` variable to the dataframe, and I tell the ggplot to colour the points according to that column.

It does work for the first selection. But whenever there are already selected points, selecting the next set of points doesn't work. I've added debug statements to see what data is returned from plotly, and it seems like it returns different `pointNumber` and `curveNumber` after the initial selection. I couldn't find any documentation about how these variables work and I'm not sure how to fix this issue.

Here's a [GIF showing the issue](https://video.twimg.com/tweet_video/DKDdqCMWkAEirkv.mp4)

And here's code to reproduce:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    click_data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "select")
    select_data <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = "select")
    data <- mtcars
    data$col <- "black"
    if (!is.null(select_data)) {
      cat(str(select_data))
      idx <- select_data$pointNumber + 1
      data[idx, "col"] <- "blue"
    }
    if (!is.null(click_data)) {
      cat(str(click_data))
      idx <- click_data$pointNumber + 1
      data[idx, "col"] <- "red"
    }
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(mpg, wt, col = I(col))) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(p, source = "select")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've also been told that perhaps what I need to do is create my own row identifier and pass it to the `key` aesthetic. I'm not sure what that means I tried defining `key <- row.names(data)` and then passing `key=key` to ggplot's aes(), but that didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 7):

Carson Sievert answered my question [on a gist](https://gist.github.com/daattali/9440f0b278dbbf538b3587e026811426#gistcomment-2207525)

Here's the answer:

I know it seems counter-intuitive, but pointNumber isn't a reliable row identifier. Use a key variable like this:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

mtcars$key <- row.names(mtcars)
mtcars$col <- "black"

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    click_data <- event_data("plotly_click")
    select_data <- event_data("plotly_selected")
    if (!is.null(select_data)) {
      mtcars[mtcars$key %in% select_data$key, "col"] <- "blue"
    }
    if (!is.null(click_data)) {
      mtcars[mtcars$key %in% click_data$key, "col"] <- "red"
    }
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, col = I(col), key = key)) + 
      geom_point()
    ggplotly(p) %>% layout(dragmode = "lasso")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you for this - any idea how we can pass the `key` identifier directly to `plot_ly` without using `ggplotly` wrapper ? also, is there any logic to the `curveNumber`, `pointNumber` that could possibly be exploited ?

Comment: @asifzuba I added an answer showing an approach directly using `plot_ly`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the `plot_ly` way, using the `customdata` attribute:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

mtcars$key <- row.names(mtcars)
mtcars$col <- "black"

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    click_data <- event_data("plotly_click", priority   = "event")
    select_data <- event_data("plotly_selected", priority   = "event")
    if (!is.null(select_data)) {
      mtcars[mtcars$key %in% select_data$customdata, "col"] <- "blue"
    }
    if (!is.null(click_data)) {
      mtcars[mtcars$key %in% click_data$customdata, "col"] <- "red"
    }
    p <- plot_ly(mtcars, x = ~mpg, y=~wt, colors = ~sort(unique(col)), color = ~col, customdata = ~key, type = "scatter", mode = "markers") %>% layout(dragmode = "lasso")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

`plot_ly` can also handle the `key` argument in the same way. However, `customdata` is the more [official way](https://plotly-r.com/linking-views-with-shiny.html#shiny-plotly-inputs):

> The key attribute is only supported in shiny, but customdata is
>   officially supported by plotly.js, and thus can also be used to attach
>   meta-information to event

The documentation can be seen via:

```
library(listviewer)
schema(jsonedit = interactive())
```

Navigate: object ► traces ► scatter ► attributes ► customdata

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe map it against the variables your are plotting:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    click_data <- event_data("plotly_click", source = "select")
    select_data <- event_data("plotly_selected", source = "select")

    data <- mtcars

    data$col <- "black"
    if (!is.null(select_data)) {
      idx <- which(data$mpg %in% c(select_data[3]$x) | data$wt %in% c(select_data[4]$y))
      data[idx, "col"] <- "blue"
    }
    if (!is.null(click_data)) {
      idx <- click_data$pointNumber + 1
      data[idx, "col"] <- "red"
    }
    p <- ggplot(data, aes(mpg, wt, col = I(col))) + geom_point()
    ggplotly(p, source = "select")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: I purposely stayed away from that because I'm afraid the x/y returned might not always be precisely identical to the values in the original data. I'm trying to understand how the pointNumber/curveNumber work, it seems very strange to me but obviously there's got to be some logic behind it