# Retrieve Selected Points from ggplotly in Another Part of Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

#### Desired Outcome

I would like to be able to click a point in my `plotly::ggplotly()` graph within my {shiny} app and then display some info about that point in a separate output below.

#### MRE

In this simple example I can make it display the `curveNumber`, `pointNumber`, `x`, `y`, but it's not easy to unambiguously retrieve a particular data point from my original data from these values. I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304639/how-to-use-plotly-to-return-the-same-event-data-information-for-selected-points) about using `key` within the `plotly::renderPlotly()` call although I'm not sure how I'd access that in a separate part of the app.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

# UI  ----
ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                verbatimTextOutput("click"))

# server  ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    p <- mtcars %>% 
      rownames_to_column("car") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl),
                 label = car)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.7)
    
    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      event_register("plotly_click")
  })
  
  output$click <- renderPrint({
    point <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", priority = "event")
    if (is.null(point)) "No Point Selected" else point
  })
}

# app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using code from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/blob/f1900cc3cd464408a60ffadfe3e95460747430e0/inst/examples/plotlyEvents/app.R) I figured out how to use `key` to identify the points and then retrieve that elsewhere from the `event_data()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

d <-  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car")

# UI  ----
ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                tableOutput("click"))

# server  ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    key <- d$car
    
    p <- d %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl),
                 key = key)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.7)
    
    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      event_register("plotly_click")
  })
  
  output$click <- renderTable({
    point <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", priority = "event")
    req(point) # to avoid error if no point is clicked
    filter(d, car == point$key) # use the key to find selected point
  })
}

# app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]