# Display data from all selected points in ggplotly

Tags: shiny, plotly, visualization, ggplotly

I would like to select points with box select in a ggplotly graph, and display the row contents in a table below the scatterplot.

There is an answer giving *almost* this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72267523/5124402), but instead of displaying all data selected by the box select tool, it only displays one row which has been clicked upon.

How would I make a table appear below the scatterplot, which contains *all* data selected with the box select tool?

Code copied from the linked answer:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)

d <-  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car")

# UI  ----
ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                tableOutput("click"))

# server  ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    
    key <- d$car
    
    p <- d %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl),
                 key = key)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.7)
    
    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      event_register("plotly_click")
  })
  
  output$click <- renderTable({
    point <- event_data(event = "plotly_click", priority = "event")
    req(point) # to avoid error if no point is clicked
    filter(d, car == point$key) # use the key to find selected point
  })
}

# app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll need to use `plotly_selected` instead of `plotly_click`.

Furthermore, please note the modified filter call using `%in%` instead of `==`.

Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(tibble)

d <-  mtcars %>% 
  rownames_to_column("car")

# UI  ----
ui <- fluidPage(plotlyOutput("plot"),
                tableOutput("click"))

# server  ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        p <- d %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = mpg, color = factor(cyl),
                 customdata = car)) +
      geom_point(size = 4, alpha = 0.7)
    
    fig <- ggplotly(p)
    event_register(fig, "plotly_selected")
    fig
  })
  
  output$click <- renderTable({
    plotly_event_data <- event_data(event = "plotly_selected", priority = "event")
    req(plotly_event_data)
    filter(d, car %in% plotly_event_data$customdata)
  })
}

# app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: result]